# Widget click calls a method on a dead Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, widget

I have a widget that when I click it, I want to create an SMS and open the Default Text Message app. I have the second part (sms creation -> intent, startactivity open Default sms app), but i cant figure out the first part.

onUpdate @ the widgetProvider class

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.sms_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.docButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS1));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.shopButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS2));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bankButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS3));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.helpButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS4));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.familyButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS5));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.runButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SMS6));
        ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, smsWidget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, views);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SmsHelper smsHelper = SmsHelper.getInstance();
    Log.d("widget", "on receive 1");
    User user= PreferencesManager.getObject("user", User.class);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(SMS1.equals(intent.getAction())){
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.sms_widget);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, smsWidget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
        smsHelper.sendSms(PHONE_NUMBER, "1 " + user.getFullName() + " " + user.getAddress());

    }
```

This is happening in the app widget provider but in order to start the default text message app i need to start it from an activity which is dead at the moment. `public class SmsHelper {

```
private static SmsHelper INSTANCE;

private SmsHelper(){

}

public static SmsHelper getInstance(){
    synchronized (SmsHelper.class){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new SmsHelper();
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}}`
```

The last line ofc is not working, as i get a NPE at ActivityThreadApplicationThread

Comment: How does this compile? `startActivity()` is not defined in `SmsHelper`. Is this an inner class of some `Activity`?

Comment: It doesn't. But i am wondering how to do it

Comment: You wrote that you get an NPE. In order to get an NPE you would have had to compile this. That's why I asked. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call `startActivity()` you need a `Context`. You should pass a `Context` in to the `sendSms()` method. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SmsHelper smsHelper = SmsHelper.getInstance();
    Log.d("widget", "on receive 1");
    User user= PreferencesManager.getObject("user", User.class);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(SMS1.equals(intent.getAction())){
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.sms_widget);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, smsWidget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
        smsHelper.sendSms(PHONE_NUMBER, "1 " + user.getFullName() + " " + user.getAddress(), context);

    }
```

and in `SmsHelper`:

```
public void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

NOTE: You will need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` since you are launching an `Activity` from a non-Activity context.